# Given orthogonal projections P and Q on a Hilbert space such that norm of P-Q is less than one. Then rank of P and Q w.r.t. Hilbert dimension same.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

Given two orthogonal projections P and Q on a Hilbert space such that $\|P-Q\|<1$. Then dim(range(P))=dim(range(Q)) w.r.t. Hilbert dimension.
Please note that the definition of Hilbert dimension means cardinality of the orthonormal basis for that Hilbert space H.
As RanP and RanQ are closed, hence they are Hilbert space so both
have an orthonormal basis, so now try to show that they are isometric isomorphisms. (Bounded isomorphism may not preserve orthonormality, that's why one should not work with that isomorphism).

Answer (score 1):

Remark that
$PQ=(I+(P-Q)) Q=P(I+(Q-P)) $
Now it is a general fact that if $\lvert \lvert T\rvert \rvert $<1,then $I+T$ is invertible. So $Q=(I+(P-Q)) ^{-1} PQ$ and $P=PQ(I+(P-Q)) ^{-1}$, this proves that the range of both $P, Q$ is isomorphic to the range of $PQ$, in particular they are isomorphic.

Comment: See here ordinary bounded isomorphism does not work actually, one has to show isometric isomorphism to show that the cardinality of the orthonormal basis of RanP and RanQ are the same. I don't want Hamel basis cardinality.